# SalesForce Formula <> 1 OR -1

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule

I wasn't able to find any documentation on this but basically, I am trying to make a Validation rule that runs when a certain thing is not correct, in my case I have 2 numbers subtracting one another the result should be either 1 or -1.

Here is the Code:

```
ISCHANGED(StageName) && (
CASE(StageName, 
"Case",1, 
"Case",2, 
"Case",3, 
"Case",4, 
"Case",5,
6) 
- 
CASE(PRIORVALUE(StageName), 
"Case",1, 
"Case",2, 
"Case",3, 
"Case",4, 
"Case",5,
6)
<>1 OR -1)  // This is returning Error of Missing " )"
```

How do I compare the calculated value against 2 numbers I tried using the In(1,-1) method but the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `ABS`.

```
ABS(/*calculation*/) <> 1
```